# Use the latest snapshot of dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

UPDATE: Simplifying my question - I have a module mod1 which is used as dependency in module mod2. I would like to make sure that mod2 always utilizes the latest version snapshot of mod1. How can I achieve that in Maven?

================

I have two modules where one module is used as dependency in another module. How can I make sure that the latest snapshot of mod1 always gets utilized in mod2? Both the modules are mentioned in the parent pom as following -

```
<modules>
   <module>mod1</module>
   <module>mod2</module>
</modules>
```

I have a release version of mod1 on remote maven repo (version 1.0). Now, in my build when there is a code chanage in mod1, it gets built as 1.1-SNAPSHOT (not deployed on remote repo). How can I make sure that mod2 utilizes this (latest) snapshot version? If mod1 source was changed then the new version 1.1-SNAPSHOT needs to be utilized in mod2 and if mod1 did not have source change then the existing latest version of 1.1 need to be utilized in mod2. Could anyone suggest how to always use latest snapshot/release here? I tried following in pom.xml for mod2 -

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>mod2</artifactId>
   <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

However, that always resolves to the release version 1.0 and never resolves to 1.1-SNAPSHOT, which is in local repo. How can I make sure that the latest snapshot gets utilized? Will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find the solution. Under dependency, adding following worked -

```
<version>[1.0-SNAPSHOT,)</version>
```

If snapshot wasn't present, it picked up the latest release, which is what I needed.

Comment: Never use version ranges, cause this makes your build not predictable and not reproducible.

Comment: It really depends on your usage and how you set it up. This allows me to do what I wanted to do as I explained in the question. I would love to explain how I could still make my builds predictable and reproducible when used in conjunction with Jenkins but that would be off topic on this question.

Answer (score 2):

The version `-SNAPSHOT` already includes the notion of "latest".

So our release cycle needs to look like this:

Before you start, you have: mod1 version is `1.0-SNAPSHOT`, mod2 version is `1.1-SNAPSHOT` and it depends on `mod1:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

Now you want to release. To do so, you remove `-SNAPSHOT` everywhere, build & deploy.

After the deployment, you bump the versions:

mod1 version is now `1.1-SNAPSHOT`, mod2 version is `1.2-SNAPSHOT` and it depends on `mod1:1.1-SNAPSHOT`

You will never have the situation that a *snapshot* version of mod2 depends on a *release* version of mod1.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, modules within the same project use the same version, by not specifying a version in the module at all. In that case Maven will fall back on the parent's version.

With that setup, `mod2/pom.xml` can have something like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In this situation you should not need to install `mod1` to your local repository at all.

Just run your `mvn` commands from the top level directory and `mod2` will be able to resolve `mod1` without trouble. Eclipse and Idea will also handle this setup correctly.

If you have a specific use-case where you need to install `mod1`, or you need the two modules to have separate version numbers, please explain that, as it might help answer the question for you better.

Lastly, you might find the [Versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) useful. It can manage your project, plugin, and dependency versions, upgrading them as necessary.

Comment: Thanks. If I always keep the same version of mod1 as mod2 then your suggestion would work. However,I do need to have ability to keep separate versions of both. mod1 is also utilized by multiple other modules. For a build, mod2 may have changed without mod1 changing in which case mod1 wouldn't build and hence will still have earlier version, which needs to be referred in mod2 pom. However, if mod1 was changed along with mod2 then both of them would be on the same new version (1.1-SNAPSHOT) and in that case I need to make sure 1.1-SNAPSHOT of mod1 gets utilized in mod2 pom. Possible?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible. Your best bet is probably to manage mod2's pom.xml of the mod1 dependency version with the versions plugin. It is bad practice to use LATEST or anything like that because the build will never be stable. Based on your comments, you should not need to install the resources to the local repository, you should be able to compile from the top level directory.